# Redbean php R::freeze(true) not working

Tags: php, redbean

I have used `R::freeze(true);` in my php application.
But I don't know why redbean alters my database table structure.
I noticed that interger type column becomes text automatically.

Also i have updated variable
`protected $isFrozen = TRUE;`
in rb.php.
But no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your PHP structure or framework (if any), it's impossible to provide any answer in relation to that.  In any event, R::freeze( true ) is the correct syntax.  Make sure you add the statement in the beginning of your application.

I have a lot of SlimPHP applications using ReadBean and I put it at the very top of my index.php right after running `R::setup();`

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
R::setup();
R::freeze( true );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Jeremy Schaffer,

```
R::freeze(true);
```

The above code is correct.
But my application uses multiple database connection.
and then i realize that for every connection we need to use above line of code to freeze db structure.

The problem is resolved.

Comment: how to add multiple mysql database/ server  connection

Comment: Suppose if you have already connected to one DB then use R::addDatabase('DB2', remaining_params); First param db name is unique for each connection.
Then use R::selectDatabase('DB2');  to select new connected database.
After connecting database use R::selectDatabase('DB2'); to select the required DB.